# Placing images alternatively in folder in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, file, for-loop

I have 2 types of image files in one folder like this:

type1-858files

type2-472files

They are in this fashion:

```
1 copy(1),1 copy(2)..........1 copy(858) and

2 copy(1),2 copy(2)..........2 copy(472)
```

I have to arrange files like this alternatively:

1 copy(1),2 copy(1),1 copy(2),2 copy(2)...........

What is the matlab code i can try for this?

Comment: Try [dir()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) and the some kind of sort...

Comment: This may be an issue. The sorting is done by windows. You may need to rename the files so that the sorting is becomes correct by windows standards.