# Odd numbering of files from one folder to other in matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, for-loop, dir

Files present in one folder:

1 copy(1).jpg,

1 copy(2).jpg

.......

.......

.......

1 copy(800)

Odd numbering of files and save it in other folder.Desired output shown below:

1.jpg,

3.jpg,

5.jpg

....

....

....

799.jpg

Source code i tried:

```
a ='C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\jumbled test\copiedimages\';
A =dir( fullfile(a, '*.jpg') );
fileNames = { A.name };
for iFile = 1 : numel( A )
  newName = fullfile(a, sprintf( '%d.jpg',iFile+2) );
  movefile( fullfile(a, fileNames{ iFile }), newName ); 
end
```

But i cant able to get desired output.So what will be the solution?

Comment: what is the output of this code ?

Comment: @Nishant displayed file names 3,4,5.......800

Comment: What is the difference between this question and your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24268556/2545927)?

Comment: `dir` receives the files in the order as given by OS (generally by date modified) . So it is possible that `A` may not have files in a sequential order by `name` even if they are named in the folder in a sequential order. Then your output files will be jumbled. I suggest create name strings by yourself using `strcat`

Comment: @kkuilla This is just odd numbering of files like 1,3,5,7......799.Here only one type of file.In previous question we were having 2 types of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rename the files, just move them to the new directory *after* checking if they had an odd number in their file name:

```
a ='C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\jumbled test\copiedimages\';
destination = a ='C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\jumbled test\copiedimages\Odd\';
A =dir( fullfile(a, '*.jpg') );
fileNames = { A.name };
for iFile = 1 : numel( A )
    [~,name] = fileparts(fileNames{ iFile });  %// This part might not be necessary if fileNames{ iFile } is just the file name without the directory. In that case rather use name=fileNames{ iFile };
    %// Extract the number from the file name
    filenum = str2num(name(8:end-4));
    %// Check if the number is odd
    if mod(filenum,2) == 1 
        movefile(fullfile(a, fileNames{ iFile }), fullfile(destination, fileNames{ iFile }));
    end
end
```

Comment: Error at line if mod(filenum,2) = 1  : The expression to the left of the equals sign is
not a valid target for an assignment.

Comment: Error at line2:The expression to the left of the equals sign is
not a valid target for an assignment.